# Warn users they might be posting a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

When you want to vote for a question as a duplicate that was duplicated too many times, the server knows which question you **will** be referring too and already offers the options even if no one pointed out that it might be a dupe in the comments :

> [image]

Why don't we use that feature even more to prevent users from asking the same questions over and over an over again. If the server is able to understand by itself that this question is always a dupe of this other one why don't he :

- Already put this himself in the comment section
  [image]
- Warns the user that he is about to post a possible duplicate when he clicks on *Post Your Question*.

> This question might already have an answer here. Are you sure you want to ask this question as it might be put on hold as a duplicate.

I'm not sure of how hard this would be to implement but since the check is already made to see if the question is a duplicate, why not just move this check before the post is made and then, rule out some duplicates even before they get posted. Many users put them there by mistake because they were not able to find the answer they were looking for, this will link them to it and at the same time, warn the users who simply didn't care enough to search.

Answer (score 9):

There is a list of potentially duplicate questions that pops up when you type in a title for your post.  It is the OP's due dilligence to make sure they aren't asking a dupe.

Comment: *It is the OP's due dilligence to make sure they aren't asking a dupe.* this is obviously not working right now. Also I don't think punishing users for it might be a good thing since a lot of question have bad titles unrelated to the content which makes it hard to find some answers. Warning the user still seems like the best option to me.

Comment: Aside from giving them a list of possible duplicate posts (which is already being done), what else would you suggest?

Comment: `Aside from giving them a list of possible duplicate posts (which is already being done), what else would you suggest? ` : Did you read my question or... ? The whole post is the proposition.

Comment: *why not just move this check before the post is made* - This is already being done.  I thought you had something else.

Comment: Users simply don't understand what the propositions there mean. The *why not just move this check before the post is made* isn't done at all. When closing a question, if there is already a proposition, it's an obvious dupe. If this is the case, I suggest we Stop the user with a box that says "Stop, you are probably posting duplicate". Which would be way more clear than text that disappears one you type your title in because the title isn't related anymore (like I said, lot of questions have bad title) anyway, please take the time to read the full post before commenting.

Comment: You do realize that a **human** created that link, and that the software didn't make it magically appear?  You read the part on the screen that says, "Similar questions **frequently linked** or **suggested as originals**", right?

Comment: Oh it is not powered by magic? Damn... must be the algorithm that looks for duplicates that is involved then. You clearly don't understand my request here so let's stop fighting over it, read the post *completely* please and make sure you understand what I suggest because right now, you are arguing that apple aren't oranges when I am talking about bananas.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you don't seem to understand how SO works.

Comment: No. I clearly dont understand how it works at all.